# How to build a NamingStrategy with Hibernate v6.2 to prefix all columns with their table name?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I want to have all my basic columns and primary keys in the database to be prefixed with the tableName, so a 'Person' with properties 'name' and 'age' become

```
CREATE TABLE person ( person_id, person_name text, person_age int)
```

This is nice because I can use 'natural joins' quite easily with PostgreSQL.

This is currently my NamingStrategy and it **works fine with hibernate 6.1.7** (which comes with Spring Boot 3.0.5)

```
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotatedColumn;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class HibernateImplicitNamingStrategy extends 
          ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl {

@Override
public Identifier determineJoinColumnName(ImplicitJoinColumnNameSource source) {
    String name = source.getReferencedColumnName().toString().toLowerCase();
    return toIdentifier(name, source.getBuildingContext());
}

@Override
public Identifier determinePrimaryTableName(ImplicitEntityNameSource source) {
    return super.determinePrimaryTableName(source);
}

@Override
public Identifier determineBasicColumnName(ImplicitBasicColumnNameSource source) {
    try {
        Field field = source.getClass().getDeclaredField("this$0");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        AnnotatedColumn column = (AnnotatedColumn) field.get(source);
        // explicit naming oder implicit
        String tableName = column.getTable().getName().toLowerCase();
        final Identifier basicColumnName = super.determineBasicColumnName(source);
        String columnName = tableName + "_" + basicColumnName.toString().toLowerCase();
        return Identifier.toIdentifier(columnName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return super.determineBasicColumnName(source);
    }
}
}
```

When I move to **hibernate 6.2.x it does not work** anymore (which comes with Spring boot 3.1.x). The Class AnnotatedColumn had changed (and moved to another package). I changed the import like this:

```
//import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotatedColumn;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.AnnotatedColumn;
```

But the new `AnnotatedColumn` does not have a method `getTable()`. I guess I have to move to more common NamingStrategy as it looks dangerous anyhow. But this is not the question right now.

The method `getExplicitTableName` doesn't help as it only returns a tableName if you have an explicit annotation @Table(name="person")

I want to know, if there is a way to access the table name inside determineBasicColumnName ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getTable()` method has been moved to `AnnotatedColumns`. It's no more there in `AnnotatedColumn`.

Update the code to this:

```
String tableName = column.getParent().getTable().getName().toLowerCase();
```

See if this works.

Comment: doesn't help because getExplicitTableName only returns a String if you have an explicit tabel name marked with an annotation

Comment: @JanningVygen Let me check if I can find some other way.

Comment: @JanningVygen Can you try this please - `column.getParent().getTable().getName().toLowerCase();`

Comment: This works. Still strange to need to use reflection to access the tableName.  It should be part of ImplicitBasicColumnNameSource

Comment: @JanningVygen They moved the logic into `AnnotatedColumns`. I don't know why. After digging, I found out that the same logic is now present in that instead of `AnnotatedColumn`.

Comment: @JanningVygen No problem :)